# How to create a full width table with fixed height and scrolling in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am quite new in bootstrap, so I am sorry if my question is too simple.

I want to create a table that has a width as the parent container, fixed height and scroll bar if the table contains too many rows.

I have tried to do it like this:

```
<table class="table">
    <tbody style="height: 80px; overflow-y: auto;">
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>4</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

It displays full table with full width but without scrolling and the height is bigger than I need.

Also I've tried to add `display: block;`:

```
<table class="table">
    <tbody style="height: 80px; display: block; overflow-y: auto;">
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>4</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In this case the scroll bar appeared but the width of tr-tag doesn't fit the container, it's much shorter.

I have also tried to specify `width=100%` to `tr` and `td` tags without a luck. How am I supposed to solve my task?

Comment: Do you want `table-head` to be fixed while scrolling?

Comment: @AbhishekPandey What exactly do you mean? I wouldn't like to have the header for my table.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Something like this, wrap your table in a div and then give height to wrapper instead of table.

```css
.table-wrap {
  height: 80px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-wrap">
  <table class="table">
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr><td>2</td></tr>
      <tr><td>3</td></tr>
      <tr><td>4</td></tr>
      <tr><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr><td>2</td></tr>
      <tr><td>3</td></tr>
      <tr><td>4</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

```css
tbody {
    display:block; 
    height:200px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
tr {
    display:block;
} 
th, td {
    width:250px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>R.No</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Mark1</td>
            <td>Mark1</td>
            <td>Mark1</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>test1</td>
            <td>81</td>
            <td>52</td>
            <td>62</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>test2</td>
            <td>81</td>
            <td>52</td>
            <td>62</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>test3</td>
            <td>81</td>
            <td>52</td>
            <td>62</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>test4</td>
            <td>81</td>
            <td>52</td>
            <td>62</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>test5</td>
            <td>81</td>
            <td>52</td>
            <td>62</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>test6</td>
            <td>81</td>
            <td>52</td>
           <td>62</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>test7</td>
            <td>81</td>
            <td>52</td>
            <td>62</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>test8</td>
            <td>81</td>
            <td>52</td>
            <td>62</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>test9</td>
            <td>81</td>
            <td>52</td>
            <td>62</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>test10</td>
            <td>81</td>
            <td>52</td>
            <td>62</td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You're just blurting out markup. What does that do? How does it answer the question? Explain yourself! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

Include the table in some division (div) then apply the width & height restrictions to the division via CSS styling. And set the overflow property to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

```css
tbody {
  height: 80px;
  display: block;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

tr {
  display: block;
}

td {
  width: 250px;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.